# How to send data automatically when user input on form

Tags: php, mysql, html

I have a form. That form having some field as like Name, Phone No., Email and submit button

I have an AWS hosted server. have a database also. So I want to know one thing when user will type his name, and phone no. then pass the data to my database without user pressing submit.

Please help me to implement it.

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far and describe what is not working.

Comment: Just learn about ajax, it will help you a lot

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is AJAX. I recommend you to use a library such as [JQuery](https://jquery.com/), which will make it a lot easier for you.

What you are looking for is most likely an onBlur method on your inputs. If your are typing in a textfield then it is focused, then when you change textfield it is Blurred. So you'd want something like, .

**EDIT**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Ajax</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="" method="post" id="ajaxForm">
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="name">
        <input type="text" id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="phone">
        <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="email" onfocus="validateAndSubmit()">
        <input type="submit" value="Send form">
    </form>
    <p><label id="result"></label></p>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        <!--

            var validateAndSubmit = function()
            {
                var nameValue = $("#name").val();
                var phoneValue = $("#phone").val();

                //Validate the data - Do your custom validation here
                if (nameValue.length > 3 && phoneValue.length > 5){
                    //Validation complete
                    $.post( 
                        "your_save_file.php",
                        { name: nameValue, phone:phoneValue },
                  function(data) {
                     alert("Data saved");
                  }
               );
                    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Validation completed";
                } else {
                    //Not validated, do nothing
                    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Validation failed";
                }
            };
        -->
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

This will do what you requested. However, I would not recommend you to do this. Because if a user accidently submitted the wrong data then the data will already have been sent. I would recommend you to have a submit button that will activate the function.

Comment: Actually i am going to implement this functionality on my for. So give me suggestion. my only requirement is when user fill name and phone no. and goto email then data automaticall went to database without any submission.

Comment: So only when everything is filled in you want the data to be submitted? You could do an interval, checking every 1 second or similar if the fields have been filled in, then send the data. One way do to this is to set an id to the form and a document onload function checking every second or so wheter the form is filled in or not.

Comment: Ok. will you please tell me how can i implement this 1 sec checking.

Comment: I have only html5 coding and a bland database. So i want to capture the event before filling the email id and then send it to database

Comment: Capture the event before filling? Don't you want to send the data after filling everything?

Comment: Updated my answer with a solution to your problem.

Comment: When user fill name and phone no. and going to fill email id thensend nameand phone no. to database without any notification to user.

Comment: What do you mean? Please check your comment it's hard to understand.

Comment: Listen Petter

NAME
PHONE NO.
EMAIL ID

SUBMIT


These are fields of my html form. when user comes and fill his NAME & PHONE NO. and click to fill EMAIL ID , on that time the information which was filled in NAME & PHONE NO. send to my database.

Comment: If this answer helped you please mark my answer as correct, and have a nice weekend :-)

Comment: Hi Peter, Thanks for reply but the data is not sending before click on submit button.

Comment: Hello Peter.  I have edit my code as according to you.  But name and phone no.  Not received in database. So will you please tell me how can data send to database.

Comment: You'll have to build a function for inputting your data into the database. A separate PHP file that takes the request. I suggest you to google a tutorial on this. Jquery Ajax